# Nested tabularx doesn't work with ltablex

Tags: tables, tabularx

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\hsize-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        {X}
        text \\
      \end{tabularx}}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Giving this:

[image]

But when I add `\usepackage{ltablex}` to the preamble, pdflatex starts to give an error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.16 \end{tabularx}
```

How to fix? Or, at least, use nested tables in multipage tables?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve the same with `ltxtable`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ltxtable is not shipped with MikTeX. How to install it?

Comment: See: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Answer says: "Download the content of the package directory", but there is not package directory and no dtx files for ltxtable: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable, only 1 file. Sorry.

Comment: Download `ltxtable.tex` and run `pdflatex ltxtable.tex` After this you will have a sty file.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Did that, it generated pdf documentation, ltxtable.log, ltx1.tex, ltxtable.aux, but no `sty`. Can you try on your machine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8838/discussion-between-marco-daniel-and-user4035)

Comment: @user4035 just run latex on ltxtable.tex and the .sty will be written out

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you sure, that it's reasonable to use it? This says: "ltxtable ist meines Wissens nicht mehr zu empfehlen, tabu ist meiner Erfahrung nach praktischer und einfach besser." - "ltxtable is as I know not more recommended, tabu is in my experience more practical and better" http://www.computerbase.de/forum/showthread.php?t=1101701

Comment: Personally I couldn't recommend tabu, it has some good ideas but it is gratuitously incompatible with standard latex syntax.

Comment: Try my package "cals", which supports nested tables in multipage tables.

Answer (score 3):

`ltablex` globally modifies `tabularx` making it essentially into a `longtable`. It would probably have been better had it defined a new command but anyway.

Inside the nested `\multicolumn` a multi-page `longtable` can't work anyway so you really just want the original `tabularx` in nested contexts, this defines a `\restoretx` command that gives you that and allows the example to run without error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\let\tx@\TX@endtabularx
\def\restoretx{\let\TX@endtabularx\tx@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{ltablex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\restoretx
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\hsize-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        {X}
        text \\
      \end{tabularx}}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```