# numbererd tabluarx inside tabulars

Tags: longtable, nesting, ltablex

I am generating tex documents automatically (HTML -> pandoc(tex) -> postprocess -> XELATEX), and my general table environment is `tabularx` (with usage of package `ltablex`, so these are longtables effectively).

One reason for this choice is the possibility to assign captions consistently (using package `caption`).

Sometimes need outer tabular's that should display the inner nested tabularx's with caption side-by-side.

My current result is:
[image]
which is created with this file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableHighlightRowBackground}{gray}{0.9375}
\definecolor{tablecaptionfontcolor}{RGB}{108, 117, 125}
\definecolor{arrayrulecolor}{RGB}{222,226,230}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{muted}{\color{tablecaptionfontcolor}}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedleft, font={muted,small}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{arrayrulecolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}\raggedright
    a
    \strut
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}\raggedright
    b   
    \strut
    \end{minipage}
\tabularnewline
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}\raggedright
        \begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {Xcrr}
        \bfseries
        Position & \bfseries Year 2020 & \bfseries Year 2021 \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \bottomrule
                \caption{Important Caption} \tabularnewline
        \endfoot
        \rowcolor{tableHighlightRowBackground} % this is another problem, this command applies the bg color to the complete outer row
        \bfseries A & { \bfseries 11,40 € } & { \bfseries 10,00 € } \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \strut
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}\raggedright
    d
    \strut
    \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The **desired output** would be a caption below the inner tabularx (inside the outer tabular).

See this html-counterpart:
[image]

My framework is quite flexible, there is just one invariant: The inner tabularx should be displayed as full-width table with a table caption and number.

Comment: Please make your example compilable. Currently the documentclass, the `booktabs` and `colortbl` packages as well as the definition of the color `tableHighlightRowBackground` are missing.

Comment: Please add some background information on why exactly you want to place a `longtable` inside of a `minipage` or a `tabular`. Neither of these two can break across pages.

Comment: Please also clarify the desired output. In the question you mention table and caption being displayed side-by-side. However, I can't see that in teh code you provided. Wouldn't it be easier to use the `sidenotes` or `floatrow` package in order to place the caption side-by-side with its table?

Comment: I edited my original question

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQJlR.png What do a, b and d stand for?

Comment: I think yes, your image seem to be what I am searching for. a b and c are dummy texts. Most of the time, I would have an outer table with one row and each column carrying an inner tabularx (to save space).

Comment: I have added an answer. However, I am still unsure of why you use nested tabulars here. Probably side by side minipages without the outer tabular could also work here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion based on some assumptions on the desired output. I have not changed the inner tabular with respect to avoiding the repetition of `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ltablex}
%\keepXColumns
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableHighlightRowBackground}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.9\textwidth}l@{}}
\toprule
a & b
\\
        {\begin{tabularx} {0.9\textwidth} {Xcrr}
        \bfseries
        Position & \bfseries Year 2020 & \bfseries Year 2021 \\
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{tableHighlightRowBackground} % this is another problem, this command applies the bg color to the complete outer row
        \bfseries A & { \bfseries 11,40 € } & { \bfseries 10,00 € } \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}}
        \captionof{table}{Important Caption}
& 
d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Concerning your bfseries-remark: is the repetition a problem? I did not manage to format a full line bold face without `bfseries` or `textbf{...}`

Comment: So if I use the inner part (tabularx with captionof afterwards) alone, where is  the caption placed? does this work for multipage tables?

Comment: @olidem: The repetition itself is not necessarily a problem but avoiding it shortens the code and makes your life easier ifyou decide you don't want the bold text. Regarding the inner tabularx: What to do entirely depends on the desired behaviour: Do you want your table to float? If so, use the `table` environment with `\caption`, not `\captionof`  and `tabularx` inside. If not, stick with `\captionof` and `tabularx`. In order to make sure caption and table stay on the same page, surround both with a `minipage` (or `center` environment if you want to horizontally center the table on the page).

Comment: Regarding multi page tables: For them you definitely need `longtable` (or a derived package such as `xltabular`.) Which package to use specifially again depends on the table, the requirements and the desired output. However, please keep in mind that a `longtable` can not be used inside of `table` or inside of a `tabular`.

Comment: Yeah that's the point. My problem is that the inner table is the result of a placeholder which can occur (depending on user action) just in the document body directly or nested in a manually created outer table. But the placeholder is currently invariant under its placement. And it can become long. I saw a command to restore the original (non-multipage) version of tabularx here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134010/209995 but couldn't get it to work. This would be a solution as I could reset the environment in outer tabulars